# Is there any tool to test the Rectangle Coordinates before using them in the code?

Tags: asp.net, coordinates, imagemap

I am using ASP.NET Rectangle in order to specify a hotspot in the image. I am struggling with determining the coordinates. **So is there any tool that helps me in drawing the coordinates?**

For example, I don't know where is the location of these coords = 0,0,82,126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Image Map Editor to find the coordinates. Have a look [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aImage_map_resources#Image_Map_Editors).

You can use Online Image Map Editor. I have found [Online Image Map Editor](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap) as easy and useful tool.